# What software can I use to encrypt all files that are copied out of a Windows system?

Tags: windows, security, encryption

What software can I use to encrypt all files that are copied out of the system (USB, network, email, etc.) such that only systems with the same encryption will be able to read the files? OS is Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example: what OSes are involved? How much are you willing to spend when it comes to paid solutions? Are you expecting encryption to kick in automatically and only on "export" (I doubt that such a thing exists)?

Comment: I think that you want this to happen automatically. If so, please update the question to make it clear (I believe that the answer is that it cannot be easily done)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a password, there are many options. [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html) is one of them and perhaps the most reliable. You can create a key file in it and prevent the data from being decrypted on any system that has no access to that file.